# Getting screen width as a variable for resizing

Tags: css, resize, width, screen

I want to get the screen width as a variable for a simple if statement.  Basically if the screen is > 768 it will display the normal website.  If it's < 768 than it displays a more compact version.  It's just a little fix for ipad resolution.  I already know how to update the webpage once i get the info, just how do I get the values in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CSS3 media queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

```
/* Any CSS for bigger screens / default CSS goes outside the brackets */

div {
    /*here*/ 
}

p {
    /*or here*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

   /*css specific to small screens under 768px width here*/

   div {
       /*here*/ 
   }

   p {
       /*or here*/
   }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

use javascript..
there is a property called

.screenwidth()

here is a link:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Further reading: 
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/